# Duplicate key violates unique constraint

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, sequence, primary-key

I have table history in which I write logs.

When I want to insert log, I get error:

> 23505:Duplicate key violates unique constraint!

Here is my function

```
public static void InsertLog(JobLogs log)
{
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(AppForms.connectionString))
        {
            string insert = "Insert into jat.history Values (@jobid, @year, @number, @datetime, @operator, @activity, @desc, nextval('jat.history_h_id_seq'))";
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(insert, con))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(insert);
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobid", log.JobId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", log.jobMark.Year);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", log.jobMark.JobNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", log.Time);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operator", log.Operator.GetFullName());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activity", log.Activity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", DBNull.Value);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }

    }
```

Table history has only one primary key and it is -> h_id. When I change insert query to this:

```
 string insert = "Insert into jat.history Values(@jobid, @year, @number, @datetime, @operator, @activity, @desc, (select max(h_id) + 1 from jat.history))";
```

It is working properly, but i heard that i should use sequences in multi-user applications, so what is wrong with my first function and first query?

**EDIT**:
When I run these two queries as I am recommended to, I get following results:

```
" (SELECT last_value FROM jat.history_h_id_seq)"; -- result:282

"SELECT (SELECT MAX(h_id) FROM jat.history)"; -- result:290
```

Comment: If you're using a sequence, your table should be configured to automatically use the `nextval` of the sequence. In regular use you should never be manually calling `nextval` yourself. Most likely you table isn't setup correctly, so the sequence hasn't been keeping up with the actual table values, so calling `nextval` returns a number that has already been entered manually in some other way.

Comment: @eurotrash so what u recommend me, how to insert highest id into database

Comment: Can you post the table schema? It will tell me how the table is setup, and I can tell you what to do from there.

Comment: Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @mikisa This query should return 2 values; run it and post the results: `SELECT (SELECT MAX(h_id) FROM jat.history), (SELECT last_value FROM jat.history_h_id_seq)`

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. PS Clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: @eurotrash for first query i get 290, for second i get 282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table definition, the `h_id` field is `h_id serial NOT NULL`. The `serial` bit means that a sequence was created for this field, such that every time you insert a new record into this table, the `h_id` field by default will be the value of `nextval('jat.history_h_id_seq')`.

When a field has been setup like this, under most circumstances you should never manually specify that field and a value in an INSERT command, because that means `nextval('jat.history_h_id_seq')` won't be called and incremented, and that can cause the sort of problems you're experiencing.

---

For example, let's create a new table: `CREATE TABLE t (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, txt TEXT);`. A sequence named `schema_name.t_id_seq` will have been automatically created along with the table. I've also put a primary key on `id`, as it's also your table's PK.

Now insert a new record correctly: `INSERT INTO t (txt) VALUES ('hello');` That will create a record containing the values `id: 1, txt: 'hello'`. I didn't specify `id` at all, but it automatically got the value 1. If I insert another record in the same way, `id` of the new record will be 2.

Instead I'll insert a new record incorrectly: `INSERT INTO t (id, txt) VALUES (2, 'bye');`. That works fine, but I manually set `id`'s value, which means the sequence wasn't used, so its "next value" is still 2. Now if I insert another record correctly: `INSERT INTO t (txt) VALUES ('test');`, it will fail with a unique violation error, because it's trying to use the sequence's `nextval` value (2) for `id`, but a record with that id already exists because I specified that field manually.

---

Anyway that's the problem with your data. And as per the queries you ran to get the `MAX(h_id)` from your table, and the value of `last_value` from your sequence, you have higher ids in your table than your sequence, whereas the highest id in your table should be the same as (or lower than) your sequence's `last_value`.

To fix this then, first update the sequence to the max id from your table: `SELECT SETVAL('jat.history_h_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(h_id) FROM jat.history));`

That will update your sequence's current value to the highest id in your table, so the next time the sequence is used, the next id (last/current + 1) will be higher than anything in your table, so will not be a duplicate.

And the second part is to make sure you never specify `h_id` in any insert statement. Just allow it to get the next value from the sequence automatically. Otherwise you'll run into this issue again.